# How do I put two or more images side by side in HTML?

Tags: css, html, css-float

Say I have 2 images and I want to place them side by side with a few spaces between them, how do I do that? I heard something about float? What is it and how can/would I use it?

Comment: So put them. What's the problem? Images by default are not blocks.

Comment: Pardon? I don't understand?

Comment: Whats. The. Problem. Putting. Them. Side. By. Side.

Comment: The problem is I don't know how thats why I'm asking

Comment: <img src="xxx.jpg" > <img src="yyy.jpg">

Comment: Just don't forget that to be able to get them side by side, there has to be enough room (width) for them. 
If there's not enough space (therefore width of image1 + width of image2 > width of the element they are contained in), they just won't be side by side with default CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usually images will behave like floating left, so as nicael pointed out, you can just place them next to each other. or you can use `style="float:left;"` as stated in the first answer. on the other hand, the image element has a nice align attribute, which allows manipulation in that way:

```html
 <p>Some Text above</p>
    <img src="http://urlref.at/images/3o.gif" align="left" />
    <img src="http://urlref.at/images/3o.gif" align="left" />
    <img src="http://urlref.at/images/3o.gif" />
    <p>Some Text underneath</p>
```

Then you would not put the align left in the last image so the text goes underneath and not next to the image.

To Space the image you can use `vspace` and `hspace` attributes:

```html
<p>Some Text above</p>
    <img src="http://urlref.at/images/3o.gif" align="left" hspace="20" />
    <img src="http://urlref.at/images/3o.gif" align="left" hspace="20" />
    <img src="http://urlref.at/images/3o.gif" hspace="20" />
    <p>Some Text underneath</p>
```

Cleaner but more complex is using plain CSS styles.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean that they will otherwise stack above and below each other? Float both images left `float:left;` and if you want to have a gap between them then use [Margin](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) or [Padding](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp).